# How to do this on every frame?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

In my main timeline I have this code

```
var screen:App42LeaderBoard = new App42LeaderBoard(1);
```

and in that class in .as file I have public var which changes, so basically with this code it only loads the first value, how can I make this

```
var screen:App42LeaderBoard = new App42LeaderBoard(1);
```

execute on every frame in onEnterFrame function in as3?

Answer (score 0):

in your timeline add and event listener for every time a new frame is entered:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameEnter);
```

and add a handler that would create a new instance of that object:

```
function onFrameEnter(e:Event):void
{
    var screen:App42LeaderBoard = new App42LeaderBoard(1);
}
```

Be careful, it looks like it could be a CPU heavy part in your code. Remember, you can always remove the listener to stop creating your objects with:

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrameEnter);
```